# Custom Translator: all attempted Model trainings end with "Trainingfailed"

Tags: microsoft-translator

Since yesterday, I have attempted several custom model trainings and, except for one of the trainings, all of them ended up with status “Trainingfailed”. And the portal does not provide any details on the reason why the trainings failed…

It is not the first time we experience this problem. It is common that a model training fails once or twice and is successful on the third or fourth attempt, always with the same training data.

Can you assist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing an issue that has now been resolved.  Training is running properly now.